# Unable to trigger NodeJS based BATCH/Exe file using jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jasmine, protractor

Im trying to execute the my batch/exe file through NodeJS script by using the:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
i.e. 
child_process.execFile For exe 
child_process.exec For Batch file
```

When I'm trying to execute my scripts by using followings **TWO** method:

1. Triggering via CMD it will be get executed successfully.
2. Triggering via Jenkins it will **NOT** get executed.

In both cases directory is same.

I have been using the followings function for this purpose:

```
exports.exec_exe_file = exec_exe_file = function(exe) 
//child_process.execFile(exe, function(error, stderr, stdout) { 
child_process.exec(exe, function(error, stderr, stdout) { if (error) { 
console.error('stderr', stderr); throw error; } //console.log('stdout', 
stdout); }); 
}
```

Called as:

```
var autoit = __dirname + "\\autoit\\start_AutoitExe.bat";
//var autoit = __dirname + '\\autoit\\Script.exe'; 
exec_exe_file(autoit);
```

Comment: Show your code you tried so far in your question.

Comment: @yong
please see my updated question.

Comment: How did you config in jenkins to run it? Give a screenshot of key part of the jenkins job configuration.

Comment: @yong
please see screenshot at: https://prnt.sc/kivpnk
BTW, I don't think so, there's an issue in Jenkins configuration for this item.